# Tie between Warning and American idiot?

Tags: lyrics, green-day

Is there a tie between Green Day's albums *Warning*, *Shenanigans*  and  *American Idiot*?

The album *Warning* points to a story of kids being kids (think: Fashion Victim) while the album *American Idiot* points to the kids being to lazy and going up a dark path. This makes it sound like the two are from the same person's perspective (just different times). In between the two, we learn that the narrator becomes even more deadly (think: Desensitized intro).

Comment: Can you be a little more specific in your question, as pertains to artist?  I'm assuming American Idiot is the Green Day album.  However, and granted my knowledge of Green Day is limited, I've never heard of the other two albums mentioned.  Are they all from Green Day?

Comment: Yes, Johnny Bones, these are all from Green day. The other 2 are before American Idiot, Shenanigans being a 2002 release and Warning a 2000 release.

Answer (score 4):

I have never heard any suggestion that any of their pre-Idiot albums were rock opera or any other form of concept album. [Shenanigans most certainly isn't -- Shenanigans isn't even a studio album, it's a compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shenanigans_(album)#Track_listing).

American Idiot is known as a rock opera both because the band publicly referred to it as such, and because it's lyrically quite explicit in this endeavor: Jesus of Suburbia, Are We the Waiting, St. Jimmy, Give Me Novacaine, Homecoming, and Whatshername are all quite plainly narrativistic in their lyrical approach, sharing named characters and explicitly depicting a linear sequence of events. I'll admit I don't know Warning so well, but I do not believe this is true on that album.

Comment: i guess dookie can vaguely be cast as a concept album. *chump*, *pulling teeth*, *she*, *sassafrass roots*, *when i come around*, and *in the end* are all about romantic drama, and some of these songs directly reference each other; while *burnout*, *longview*, *basket case*, and *sassafrass roots* [again] are all about mental illness & drug use (also note that chump/longivew play as a single long song). there's kind of a sense that the album directly documents the band's (especially armstrong's) life; but "concept album" is a bit of a stretch, and not something ive ever heard the band say.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the albums having been written and performed by the same people, I know of no thematic link between those three.  The album 21st Century Breakdown, however, is sort of thematically related to American Idiot in that it is also a concept/rock opera and touches most of the same themes of alienation, etc.